# fancybox 3 no title displayed

Tags: javascript, title, fancybox-3

I need to add a title when fancybox 3 opens the window as iframe.
I tried to add with helpers or other but no result

Title doesn't show. Any help?
The link is this one:

```
 <a onclick="viewdetails();"  data-caption="caption here" title="Title here" >xxx</a>
```

and the function here:

```
  function viewdetails()
        {
    
 $.fancybox.open({

  width : 1280,
   height : 720,
   fitToView : false,
   autoSize : false,
   titlePosition: 'top',
   titleShow: true,

 src  : 'page.php',
 type: 'iframe',
 scrolling: true,

 opts : {       
         modal: false,
        afterShow : function( instance, current ) {  
        },
    toolbar  : false,

    smallBtn : true,
    iframe : {
    css : {
            width  : '1280px',
            height : '800px'
        }
    }

    }
});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start Fancybox using  `$.fancybox.open()`, how can it know that you want it to use attribute from some random link on the page? Use `caption` option.

Comment: an example? it works by opening the iframe when i click on the link. only title doesn't work

Comment: Documentation contains plenty of examples - https://web.archive.org/web/20210325170940/https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-2